# Searching and Sorting vector in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, search, vector

I am building a game (on c++) for a project and I want to search for Card object in vector and I want it to return the specific index so I would be able to remove it. In addition I want to sort the Hand that is a vector of Cards by values.
The question is which Sort algorithm is optimal for vectors? (is the sort() function that vector Class provide good enough?)
Second, which Search algorithm is optimal for vectors? (I saw there is binary_search function provided on  but it doesn't return index, only bool).
Thanks!

Comment: Too broad. Have you tried benchmarking the different sorting algorithms? Show us some research.

Comment: For a 5-card hand, bogosort is probably good enough.  Why are you looking for "optimal"?

Comment: @stark because it is not a regular deck of cards, it can be as big as the user wants.

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::lower_bound like so:

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), needle);

std::size_t index = ((it != v.end()) && (needle == *it)) ?
                    std::distance(v.begin(),it) :
                    (std::size_t) - 1;
```